# Selenium Python code stopping when opening chrome with user profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, crash, selenium-chromedriver

The code works fine, it opens the browser with the user profile I want, but the code stops running in a few seconds after the browser opens, so all the code I put below the webdriver doesn't work

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\I\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") #Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Chromedrive/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Comment: what exactly you want here?

Comment: @YaDav Manish The code stops running, it doesn't report any errors, but it stops running. I want it to keep running

Comment: @YaDavMaNish Take a look, this is what happens [https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/8702310?key=0f34e6cca020e163fb3be2bdc91ff57f]

Comment: Ok, sure let me check

Comment: your given url is not having recorded video atleast I'm not able to see

Comment: @YaDavMaNish Try again pls https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/8702310?key=0f34e6cca020e163fb3be2bdc91ff57f

Comment: You can add more details like writing the error so maybe someone could help